# Is there a BEFORE SELECT trigger in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Hi I am using sqldeveloper conected to an oracle database.

My senario is I have a customer table in my database with a date field called `start_date` which holds the date of the day the user signed up and a "boolean" field called `is_member`. Each membership only lasts one year so `is_member` is false if `SYSDATE > start_date + 1year`.

I would like to do a check to see if a user is still a member (and change `is_member` if not) before the user calls a select statement. Is this possible?

If not has anyone got any ideas on how else to keep the `is_member` field up to date? Can you do a trigger that is called once a day to see if the membership has expiered?

Thanks in advace! =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a table column to store dependent data, use a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW customer_v AS
SELECT c.*, 
       CASE WHEN SYSDATE > add_months(c.start_date, 12) 
          THEN 'FALSE' 
          ELSE 'TRUE' 
       END is_member
  FROM customer c
```

The `is_member` view column will always contain up-to-date data.

Comment: and how will this work for people who renew their memeberships?

Comment: @HLGEM: The described business rule may be an oversimplification of the actual business rule. In that specific case however, we could suppose that the `start_date` is updated when a customer renews its membership.

Comment: when they renew their membership the start_date will be updated.

Comment: As data person, I would never update the startdate on a renewal, you lose the total amount of time the person has been a member.

Comment: thanks for the answer Vincent the solution works great!! =D 


@HLGEM How would you store it if they renewed it then?

Comment: I would store the end date as well as the begin date. WHen they renew you update the enddate.

Comment: @geekman92, you could have a `renewal_date` but I would prefer a table `renewals`, unique on `member_id` an `renewal_date`

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a `BEFORE SELECT` trigger in PL/SQL.

It sounds like `is_member` should not be a column in a table at all but should be something that is computed in a view.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name
AS
  SELECT <<list_of_columns>>
         (CASE WHEN sysdate > add_months(start_date, 12)
               THEN 'Y'
               ELSE 'N'
           END) is_member
    FROM your_table
```

Your code would then simply query the view rather than querying the base table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the application to do the checking not a trigger. Triiger do not fire on SELECT.

As far as keeping the field up-to-date, there are two possibilities. First set up a nightly job to inactivate any members whose meberships have expired. Or change your struture to store membershipenddate rather than isactive and use that in the application check to see if the member is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Policy to your table and schema and Add the code that you want.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#CIHCAACD

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth_orders( 
schema_var IN VARCHAR2,
table_var  IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
return_val VARCHAR2 (400);
BEGIN
return_val := 'SALES_REP_ID = 159';
RETURN return_val;
END auth_orders;


BEGIN
DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
object_schema    => 'oe',
object_name      => 'orders',
policy_name      => 'orders_policy',
function_schema  => 'sys',
policy_function  => 'auth_orders',
statement_types  => 'select, insert, update, delete'
);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a job which is run everyday and update the is_member field.